# Unable to resolve token for FCM while implementing Push notification for Xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have clearly followed below link for implementing push notifications and while clicking on register from android simulator I get below error message from class DeviceInstallationService:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms

Error : **Unable to resolve token for FCM**

The only change I did is using FirebaseInstallations instead of FirebaseInstanceId as it says FirebaseInstanceId.Instance is depreciated.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bootstrap.Begin(() => new DeviceInstallationService());

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);

        if (DeviceInstallationService.NotificationsSupported)
        {
            FirebaseInstallations.GetInstance(Firebase.FirebaseApp.Instance).GetId();
            //FirebaseInstanceId.Instance. GetInstance(Firebase.FirebaseApp.Instance)
            //    .GetInstanceId()
            //    .AddOnSuccessListener(this);
        }

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        ProcessNotificationActions(Intent);
    }
```

Any hint on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need use `FirebaseMessaging` Class to get token. The token can be generated using the following code:

```
var token = FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
```

Regarding the Firebase InstanceId, this is what the official document says:

> This class FirebaseInstanceId is deprecated.
> Firebase Instance ID has been replaced with FirebaseInstallations for app instance identifiers and FirebaseMessaging.getToken() for FCM registration tokens.

Comment: Use this code to replace `FirebaseInstanceId` and do the operation you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

FirebaseOptions baseOptions = FirebaseOptions.FromResource(Android.App.Application.Context);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder(baseOptions).SetProjectId(baseOptions.StorageBucket.Split('.')[0]).Build();
FirebaseApp.ClearInstancesForTest();
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Android.App.Application.Context, options);
var refreshedToken = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).